# How to get coordinates of Y axis in Ipad or Iphone?

Tags: jquery

I want the coordinates of y-axis when the user start swapping the 
screen in iPad / touch phones to the end where he leaves the finger.
want start and end coordinates. How to get that without any plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best (most updated) method of doing so but [this post](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios-accelerometer-websockets-html5) might help you out.

```
window.ondevicemotion = function(event) {
    // event.accelerationIncludingGravity.x
    // event.accelerationIncludingGravity.y
    // event.accelerationIncludingGravity.z
}
```

**Update:**
A more recent post still uses the same methods: http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/07/javascript-accelerometer/